# How to solve three parameters and get the error squared minimization using scipy.minimize?

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, solver, minimize

I have the following model to predict the "Margin of Victory of the Home Team(home MOV)":

**model = HAdv + (HT * homeSkills) + (AT * awaySkills)**

Where "HAdv" is home field advantage, "HT" is home team, "AT" is away team and "homeSkills" & "awaySkills" is the skills of the teams that are given in a pandas DataFrame with 198 samples of data that also includes the "Home MOV" column for each game.

```
# Transform the panda columns values in np.array

homeSkills = games['Home Skills'].to_numpy()  
awaySkills = games['Away Skills'].to_numpy()
homeMOV = games['Home MOV'].to_numpy()
```

All I want to do is to solve the variables (HAdv, HT, AT) and obtain the minimum values for the to get a Sum of Squared Errors (SSE) minimized.

**SSE = ((model - HomeMOV)^2).sum()**

Where "homeMOV" is the array settled before with data given by a DataFrame.

here is my code:

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize

# INITIAL CONDITIONS
HAdv_0 = 100. 
HT_0 = 100.
AT_0 = 100.

v0 = [HAdv_0, HT_0, AT_0]
# DATA TO BE ANALIZED
Y = homeMOV

def model (v, p):
    # Unpack variables
    HAdv, HT, AT = v
    
    # Unpack parameters
    homeSkills, awaySkills = p
    
    # Model
    f = HAdv + (HT * homeSkills) + (AT * awaySkills)
    return f

def sum_of_squares(Y,v,p):
    f = model(v, p)
    obj = np.array(((f - Y)**2)).sum()
    return obj

res = minimize(sum_of_squares, v0, options={'disp':True})
```

I'm getting the following error: *sum_of_squares() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'v' and 'p'*

I don't know if this is the unique error. I think there's something else that I'm not able to settle up in this minimization. Can someone help with this task that I'm stuck in almost 2 weeks trying to solve this values, please. Thanks a lot.

Comment: What parameters does `minimize()` need?

Comment: cipy.optimize.minimize(fun, x0, args=(), method=None, jac=None, hess=None, hessp=None, bounds=None, constraints=(), tol=None, callback=None, options=None)    I put the function and initial guesses. I don't know if I set it up in the correct way, I tried some other ways, including args, but I couldn't run the minimize.

Comment: And what is the 'signature' of `fun`?  That is, how should the first argument of `minimize` be defined?

Comment: my 'fun' is the sum_of_squares function, and my initial guesses is v0 as a list. 'fun' in minimize parameters is just a indication that the objective function goes there, but it doesn't need to be named 'fun' as well.

Comment: Point me to the documentation on minimize().

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are almost there.

Let me slightly change the notations for better readability:

- `v` => `coeffs`: the variables to optimize
- `p` => `X` => the input data

Then, your code looks like:

```
def model(coeffs, X):
    # Unpack variables
    HAdv, HT, AT = coeffs
    
    # Unpack parameters
    homeSkills, awaySkills = X
    
    # Model
    f = HAdv + (HT * homeSkills) + (AT * awaySkills)
    return f


def sum_of_squares(coeff, X, Y):
    f = model(coeff, X)
    obj = np.array(((f - Y)**2)).sum()
    return obj
```

From there, you need to pass `X` and `Y` to the `sum_of_squares` function (`coeff` will be managed automatically by scipy). This is achieved by the `args` parameter in `minimize`:

> **Extra arguments passed to the objective function** and its derivatives (fun, jac and hess functions).

So, in your case:

```
res = minimize(sum_of_squares, v0, args=(X, Y), options={'disp':True})
```

Finally, you can check the fit status with:

```
res.success
```

and find the fitted `coeff` (HAdv, HT, AT) in:

```
res.x
```

Comment: Yeah. That's totally  helped to solve my ask. Thank you.

Answer (score -2):

It looks like you need 3 args for `sum_of_squares`.  But by saying `minimize(sum_of_squares, v0, options={'disp':True})`, only 2 are provided:

Y: provided by `minimize`
v: v0
p: *missing*

I don't think the "options" count as "p".